# How can I add elements of a list using my own function bin_add

Tags: python, list, function

I defined my own `bin_add` function that adds binary numbers. I am having a hard time trying to use that function to add elements of a list

I tried using

```
for i in add_list:
    result = bin_add(i,result)
```

but it doesn't work because `bin_add` doesn't return value.

I tried the following to make the function return zeros but it's still not working

```
x = convert(bin_list)
    return convert(x)
```

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: why not make your `bin_add` function return a value?